# Changing colour of a View every second within a time limit

Tags: android

I Have a `View` and i want change `BackgroundColor` of the view within a time limit. Lets say i want change the colour of the `View` to Red and Green every sec for a 20 min.

**What i already tried:**

```
final static int INTERVAL = 10000; // 1 second
    private static View myView = null;
    boolean whichColor = true;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);// set initial colour
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    updateColor();
                    whichColor = !whichColor;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void updateColor() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (whichColor) 
                    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                else 
                    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is changing colour of view every second but i want change only for a time limit. Is there any way i can do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just keep reference to the counter inside `Runnable`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 20 * 60;
    int counter = 0;

    public void run() {
        while (counter < MAX_COUNT) {                
            try {
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            counter++;
            updateColor();
            whichColor = !whichColor;
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Alternative:

Use `Handler` class and it's messages system.

Create class that extends `Handler`:

```
public class BlinkingHandler extends Handler {
    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 20 * 60;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.what == 123) {
            counter++;
            //Change background color
            if (counter < MAX_COUNT) {
                this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(123, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Init your `Handler`:

```
BlinkingHandler handler = new BlinkingHandler();
handler.sendEmptyMessage(123);
```

Comment: Not working the first suggstion not even changing color of view. Anyway thanks for fast replay!

Comment: i think you miss something on first code.. please have look

Comment: Is thread only works one time on run?  i am using the same function different places and it seems not working

Comment: [Yes it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2689162/6507689). It is a feature of Java langauge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code of `TransitionDrawable`

```
GradientDrawable greenDrawable=new GradientDrawable();
greenDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
GradientDrawable redDrawable=new GradientDrawable();
redDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
Drawable[] drawables={greenDrawable,redDrawable};
final TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable=new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setBackground(transitionDrawable);
CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(1000*60*20,1000) {
  @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        transitionDrawable.startTransition(1000);
    }
  @Override
    public void onFinish() {
       //finished 1000*60*20 milliseconds
      }
};
countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: Are you tested this? setColor and setBackground throwing cannot resolve error